# Cassandra Keyspace name with hyphen (-)

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

I am using cassandra 1.2.15 version. Using cassandra CQL Java driver I will be creating a keyspace. My problem is I can't able to create a keyspace which contains hyphen (test-hyphen).

Code:

```
String query = "CREATE KEYSPACE \"test-hyphen\" WITH REPLICATION = { 'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 }"
resultSet = session.execute(query)
```

When I tried to do so I am getting following exception:

> java.lang.Exception: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: "test-hyphen" is not a valid keyspace name

Any work around or any possible way to create keyspace with hyphen in between the characters?

Comment: Why do you insist on having a hyphen in the keyspace name when Cassandra tells you quite clearly that it's not allowed? You could use an underscore instead of a hyphen: `test_hypen`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### This cannot be done.

[From the documentation:](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/create_keyspace_r.html)

> Keyspace names are 32 or fewer alpha-numeric characters and underscores, the first of which is an alpha character. Keyspace names are case-insensitive. To make a name case-sensitive, enclose it in double quotation marks.